# Input field value 'undefined' even with value in it

Tags: javascript, html, gatsby

I am trying to make a login form. for some reason i am getting an error my input is 'null' or undefined even when I fill out the form and submit

```
<form name ="loginform"  onSubmit ={validate()} method ="post">
      <p>Email</p>
    <input id = "mail"   type = "email"  name = "usr" placeholder = "Enter Email" required></input>
    <p>Password</p>
    <input id ="pass" type ="password"  name ="pword"  placeholder = "Enter Password" required></input>


     <input type = "submit"   name ="" value ="Login"  ></input> <br /> 
    <a id ="demo" href ="#" style={{color:'white'}} >Forget Password?</a><br />
    <a href = "#" style ={{color:'white'}}>need help?</a>
</form>




  function validate(){

  var un =document.getElementById("mail").value;
  var pw = document.getElementById("pass").value;

  var usernames = "username"; 
  var passwords = "password" ;
  if ((usernames ===  un) && (passwords === pw)) {
      window.location = " index.js ";
      return false;
  }
  else {
      alert ("Login was unsuccessful, please check your username and password");
  }
  }
```

-Here is the function and I get this error: TypeError: Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference. any help is apprectaed

Comment: `</input>` is unnecessary; in fact it's not valid. `<input>` is a no-content tag so you need no closing tag.

Comment: Notice, that `window.location` can't be changed while there's a pending server call.

Comment: Also, you're setting `window.location` with extra spaces in it `" index.js "`, as well as sending the browser to js instead of html.

Comment: It looks like the page is heavily frameworked, please check what is actually rendered to the page, maybe your original inputs have been replaced with some other elements ..?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following changes:

1. in your var username use `var usernames= "email@test.com";` as your input is an email.
2. While adding CSS style on each line is considered bad practice, you can do it with this syntax: `style = "color:white"` and add, change whatever attributes you want to change. 
   **NOTE: White text color on white page will hide it for you.**
3. Various html errors, I suggest use test your HTML code here every time: **https://validator.w3.org/**

Here is the final document I have for you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <!-- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> -->
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css"> -->
    <script>
        function validate() {
            var un = document.getElementById("mail").value;
            var pw = document.getElementById("pass").value;
            var usernames = "email@test.com";
            var passwords = "password";
            if ((usernames === un) && (passwords === pw)) {
                //window.location = " index.js ";
                //return false;
                alert("Login was Succesful"); // GOES HERE IF LOGIN WAS SUCCESSFUL
            }
            else {
                alert("Login was unsuccessful, please check your username and 
                      password");
            }
        } 
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="loginform" onSubmit={validate()} method="post">
        <p>Email</p>
        <input id="mail" type="email" name="usr" placeholder="Enter Email" required>
        <p>Password</p>
        <input id="pass" type="password" name="pword" placeholder="Enter Password" 
          required>
        <input type="submit" name="Login" value="Login"><br />
        <a id="demo" href="#" style="color: white">Forget Password?</a><br />
        <a href="#" style="color: white">need help?</a>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```